# Find an EC2 instance by its IP in boto3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I want to find an EC2 instance using its public and private IPs. In CLI it can be done through:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filter Name=ip-address,Values=IP_1,..IP_N
```

However, I am looking for a way to do this using `boto3` in `Python`:

```
import boto3
ec2 = boto3.resource("ec2")
for instance in ec2.instances.all():
    # if instance.ip['private'] == '1.2.3.4': # Something like this.
```

Comment: Use `.filter()` instead of `.all()`.

Comment: `instance.private_ip_address`
More: 
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2/instance/private_ip_address.html

Comment: If you have a CLI command using `ec2 describe-instances`, and you are trying to reproduce that in Python, why would you not use the boto3 EC2 client's `describe_instances` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One better option is to use **Filters** on the ec2 client describe_instances method. Variety of filters available is listed [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2/client/describe_instances.html)

[This](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html) is the reference for ec2 boto3

Sample code that I tried

```
ec2_client = self.get_ec2_client(aws_credentials)
ec2_client.describe_instances(Filters=[{
                'Name': 'private-ip-address',
                'Values': [
                    '10.273.117.10',
                ]
            }
            ])

 def get_ec2_client(self, aws_credentials):
        client = boto3.client('ec2', aws_access_key_id=aws_credentials["aws_access_key_id"],
                              aws_secret_access_key=aws_credentials["aws_secret_access_id"])
        return client
```